# why other database name wont work in android except database (WebSQL)

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, web-sql

I have This code in javascript

```
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);    
        alert("No Error");
```

Above the code is work and the android emulator will show NO Error , but once i change the Database name to other like

```
        var db = window.openDatabase("Databasee", "1.0", "Cordova Demoo", 200000);  
        alert("No Error");
```

The second part of code won't show No Error due to it hits error somewhere in window.openDatabase

What is the problem of it ? is it only able to use Database as name ??

Comment: Why you are using JavaScript for connection?

Comment: @dholakiyaankit because is a HTML5 project

Comment: @dholakiyaankit: This is a cordova hybrid project..

Comment: @purus can you explain little bit more don't have a idea about it

Comment: visit http://cordova.apache.org/ and www.phonegap.com

Comment: Have you try with android 4.4 emulator?

Comment: i solve the problem by removing and re-install , i guess android does not support on time create db like chrome

Answer (score 0):

**You can use any name for database and it does not matter.** Have you tried to catch the error and display it?

Also do you get any warnings in developer console?

Have you checked in chrome resource whether you have the database already created?

Refer to http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

Comment: In Chrome it doest not have any error..only in android emulator

Comment: The fact is that you can use any database name.. Hope that was your question. You add some code to do alert on datbase insert and select. Also you saw the database in your chrome resource?

Comment: I was asking are you able to see the database if there or not? in chrome "resource" tab.